# Android Phone Call receivers doesnt work

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

i want to test handling phone calls, so i made a little app, it should write a log on a incoming/outgoing phone call. here are the broadcast receivers:
1st:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("DEBUGING", "INCOMING CALL DETECTED !!");

     }
}
```

The second one:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("DEBUGING", "OUTGOING CALL DETECTED !!");

     }
}
```

And finally the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.callrec"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And the problem is that my recievers are never called .... and i have no idea why, can anyone help?

Comment: so i found out that this works on Android 2.2 and doesnt work on 4.0+ does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently from 3.1+ your receivers will start working only after the user does something with your activity at least once, so my app without an activity will not work

Comment: You are 100% right... I was having a similar problem and now opening an activity it worked. Thanks.